# Linux script, prompting/reading + String equality operator + Regex

Tags: linux

This is a simple question which I've been struggling over all weekend. I want to prompt the user to type [TtMm] and if he/she doesn't, to prompt again. The interpreter spots some syntax errors which I don't understand.

Thank you,

```
#!/bin/bash

use_selection=H
while [ $use_selection != [TtMm]  #interpreter says this is missing a `
do
echo "Get Target (T/t) or name (M/m)"
read use_selection
echo $use_selection
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this in *portable* shell is

```
#! /bin/sh

while :; do 
    echo "Get Target (T/t) or name (M/m)?"
    read use_selection
    case "$use_selection" in
        [TtMm]) break;;
             *) echo "Invalid selection" >&2;;
    esac
done
echo "$use_selection"
```

It can also be done with [`expr`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/expr) but that has more portability gotchas.

Do not write unportable shell scripts; in particular, never use Bash extensions.  If you are in a situation where an extension appears to be the path of least resistance, you will almost surely be happier if you stop and rewrite the entire script in a better language, e.g. Perl or Python.

Comment: "never use Bash extensions" - a very questionable advice considering Bash popularity and availability everywhere.

Comment: @OlegGryb I would dispute the "availability everywhere", but that's not the point: the point is that the moment you want to use a Bash extension, or a GNU coreutils extensions, or any other piece of shell functionality that's not in POSIX.1-2001, even, that is a reliable indication that **it is time to switch to a better scripting language.**

Comment: Please do dispute by naming a Linux that doesn't support it. If you're concerned about porting to the older UNIX systems, it might be an issue. Otherwise, I would stick to bash.

Comment: If you're writing a shell script rather than some other kind of script, then you *must* either be concerned about porting to "older UNIX" (which, btw, includes several quite recent OSes of the \*BSD persuasion), or be trying to fit into limited space such that all you have is `busybox`, because *why would you write a shell script if you didn't have to?*

Comment: ... in fact, AFAIK, it is actually the case that Perl (as long as you stick to the core interpreter and to features that were in 5.6 or so) is *more* likely to be available than Bash, these days.

Comment: Because usability of bash is better than that of sh. Making code compatible with all possible platforms in the world is unnecessary burden that can consume a lot of resources. All important OS'es that I care about including BSD based Darwin do support bash out of the box. If we'd stick to your arguments we would never get rid of legacy browsers still used by many people, but we both know that they are insecure and should be abandoned.

Comment: You're still missing the point: Sure, the usability of bash is better than the usability of portable sh (although not by much), but the usability of a *good* scripting language (Perl, Python, Ruby, node.js, etc) is *orders of magnitude* better than either, and nowadays those are *more* likely to be available than bash.  So, I claim that it may be appropriate to code in portable shell still, but is *never* appropriate to use Bash extensions, because anytime you could use those, *you could use an even better language instead*.

Comment: No, I still can't subscribe to that point of view. It's all about balance between installing more stuff to gain even better usability or using what's available out of the box, e.g. in embedded systems bash most likely will be available while P/R languages will not. Anyway, this discussion becomes more and more like a religious war that has too little to do with the initial question, so I would stop here. It was good communicating to you.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

use_selection=H
while [[ ! "$use_selection" == [TtMm] ]] 
do
echo "Get Target (T/t) or name (M/m)"
read use_selection
echo $use_selection
done
```

Comment: This doesn't do what was asked for: you're doing string comparison, not regexp or glob matching.

Comment: OK, I take that back: `help [[` says "When the `==` and `!=` operators are used, the string to the right of the operator is used as a pattern and pattern matching is performed."  That violates least-surprise so dramatically that I'm adding it to my list of *additional* (beyond lack of portability) reasons not to use `[[`.

Comment: I'll take is as a confirmation that it does work as expected :)